# Is there a way to import csv file from Cassandra DevCenter?

Tags: csv, import, cassandra, copy, nosql

One way to import csv file is by using `copy` command in cqlsh. I am wondering is there an effective way to import csv file from DevCenter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there currently is no way to import from CSV using DevCenter.

Comment: I really want to know why don't they develop this function... This function is so useful ...